# Redirect on button click in alert-dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I would like to show an alert box at the end of my code where the insert operation is complete. Is there an easy way to show some kind of alert box that says "Inserted successfully" and shows an OK-button. The click on "OK" should then redirect to a specific page.

The code I'm using:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
"alertMessage", "alert('Inserted Successfully')", true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alertMessage", 
 "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Inserted Successfully');window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');</script>");
```

Comment: But i want to redirect my website page. like "abc.aspx"

Comment: Okay whatever url you want whats the issue in that?

Comment: When i put full URL in window.location.replace(""). my session is clear and it directly display my login page.
Is it session problem?

Comment: First you can't redirect page just like C# code '../folder/abc.aspx' you need to give full url. For testing purpose you can give "http://localhost2556/abc.aspx" like that

Comment: Ok sir now i understand ...
Thank you so much sir...as per your code my operation is working.
Thanks again

Comment: Actually i try it sir... and get success . Thank you for your help..
and sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0):

**It simple** , just simply redirect right after the alert() call:

```
  alert('Your Text over here');
  window.location.href="your url comes here";
```

Else if you want to use Confirm box

```
 if(confirm("Your Text over here")) 
  {
    window.location.href = "your url comes here";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow either one of the approach:

**First Approach:**
You can use the alert dialog and notify the User. Once the User clicks the OK button, it will redirect to the site. But if User closes the dialog also it will redirect.

Reason: alert() method never returns any confirmation.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder javaScript = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            string scriptKey = "ConfirmationScript";

            javaScript.Append("var userConfirmation = window.confirm('" + "Inserted Successfully" + "');\n");
            javaScript.Append("window.location='http://www.YourSite.com/';");

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), scriptKey, javaScript.ToString(), true);
```

**Second Approach:**
You can use the confirm() method which will show OK & Cancel button & on User click it will tell which button got clicked.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder javaScript = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            string scriptKey = "ConfirmationScript";

            javaScript.Append("var userConfirmation = window.alert('" + "Inserted Successfully" + "');\n");
            javaScript.Append("if ( userConfirmation == true )\n");
            javaScript.Append("window.location='http://www.YourSite.com/';");

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), scriptKey, javaScript.ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for asp.net code behind c#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect", "alert('Request communication timed out!'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "default.aspx';", true);
```

Thank you